# Trying to create login with fb using django all auth

Tags: django, django-allauth

i am trying to create login system using fb using django all auth but it is showing error while template rendering No reverse match.I have tried everything from my end,please help

View

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'name.html', {})
```

Template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% load socialaccount %}
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'facebook' method='oauth2' %}">Login with Facebook</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Url file

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), url(r'^accounts/',     include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Settings file

```
"""
Django settings for muauth project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'lsd_3z4#438nu0__#-m$urx#r@li$76bcgb(j8hmx%%u%pzx@_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'music.apps.MusicConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'muauth.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'muauth.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'music',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                    # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: please add the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),` to your `urls.py` as mentionned on the [documentation of django allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

EDIT:

Did you followed theses steps?

1. Add a Site for your domain, matching settings.SITE_ID (django.contrib.sites app).
2. For each OAuth based provider, add a Social App (socialaccount app).
3. Fill in the site and the OAuth app credentials obtained from the provide

Comment: Did you followed theses steps? 
1- Add a Site for your domain, matching settings.SITE_ID (django.contrib.sites app).
2- For each OAuth based provider, add a Social App (socialaccount app).
3- Fill in the site and the OAuth app credentials obtained from the provider.